# scipy.io.loadmat returns MemoryError for big matlab structures

Tags: python, matlab, scipy, 32-bit

I want to open and process some big .mat files in python. The scipy.io.loadmat function is perfect for that purpose. However, the function returns MemoryError when the .mat files are big. The problem might be due to the python version I use (Python 2.7.10 32 bits, interfaced with spyder). This problem has already been raised but I can't find any decent solution. Ideally, I would be able to open these files without changing my python. Is there a way to make the scipy.io.loadmat function load just some variables contained in the .mat file?

Answer (score 2):

See the documentation here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.loadmat.html

You can pass a list of variable names to read from the file:

```
scipy.io.loadmat("myfile.mat", variable_names=["myvar1", "myvar2"])
```

Comment: Thanks. Notice, however, that this trick is not an appropriate solution for the long term. Any idea how to get rid of this memory error?

Comment: What do you mean?  What's the problem in the long term?

Comment: We should be able to open any .mat files with the scipy.io.loadmat() function, whatever the size of the file. It's not the case right now. I systematically get memory errors when I try to open .mat files > .1 GB

Comment: Are these files that you create on the same machine and/or are able to open MATLAB?  What sort of MATLAB structure?  Mainly matrices, or lots of cells and struct?

Comment: Matlab opens these files without any problem. They contain double and struct objects. For example, in one datafile, I have 15   205x6001 double objects (Bytes ~ 9841600 for each double).

Comment: What version of MATLAB?  Is it 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: Matlab (R2015b) 64 bits

Comment: So that's the difference there.  MATLAB is 64bits, so it has access to the whole 64bit address space for memory.  Python is 32bits, so it has access to the much, much smaller 32bit address space.  This means Python is being limited to a much smaller amount of memory.  A 32bit MATLAB would have the same problem.  In order for Python to load .mat files as large as MATLAB, then Python would also need to be 64bit.  That is just how CPU architectures work, there is nothing Python (or any other language) can do to change it.

Comment: Ok, is there a 64bit python than can be run with the spyder interface? Do numpy and scipy work with 64bit python?

Comment: Yes, Python is compatible with x86_64 CPUs (as well as other CPU architectures like ARM and PPC), and Spyder, Numpy, and Scipy all work great on 64bit CPUs.  The typical approach is to use Anaconda to install everything at once.  It includes spyder, numpy, scipy, and a bunch of other powerful tools (like matplotlib, pandas, jupyter, numba, blaze, and dask) out-of-the-box (64bit and 32bit are available but 64bit is the default).  If you are switching versions this also may be a good time to switch to python 3 as well, it has a lot of nice features, but will require some changes to your code.